# iOS-библиотека или pod для работы с google drive и dropbox?

Tags: ios, google-drive, dropbox, ios8

Нужно добавить в iOS-приложение возможность просматривать и получать файлы из google drive и dropbox'а (и iCloud) пользователя. Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, как вы ее решали? Есть ли полезная библиотека на эту тему, чтобы не писать взаимодействие с этими сервисами?

Comment: пробовали на гитхабе написать google drive ios? https://github.com/GrahamDennis/GDFileManagerKit

Comment: конечно пробовал. приведенный вами проект последний раз обновлялся два года назад, что для iOS почти вечность. Сами им пользовались в последнее время?

Comment: там их 23 штуки дает по этому критерию поиска.

Comment: ... и все ровно такие же бесполезные в практическом плане

Comment: ну как допишете свою - выкладывайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В iOS8 в UIKit появились классы [UIDocumentMenuViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentMenuViewController_Class/) и [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/), которые предоставляют возможность вытащить/закинуть файлы из популярных "облаков" (этим похоже и обьясняется, что проекты реализующую похожую функциональность на cocoapods и githab перестали поддерживаться).